# ViewPager fragments are all referencing the same RecyclerView and/or Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment that contains a RecyclerView to display events for a given day. I am using a ViewPager to separate the Fragments into multiple days; A Fragment for Saturday's events and a Fragment for Sunday's events.

However, it appears that both Fragments are referencing the same RecyclerView and/or Adapter, as it is only the last tab (in this case, Sunday) whose events are shown.

In my specific case, Saturday has two events, and Sunday has no events. Both Fragments have empty RecyclerViews. To confirm my theory that it was caused by the last tab, I switched the date. This caused both RecyclerViews to have two events (the ones from Saturday).

Here is the relevant code for the individual Fragments:

```
public class EventListFragment extends Fragment{
    private EventAdapter mEventAdapter;

    private static final String DATE_ARG = "eventDate";

    public static EventListFragment newInstance(LocalDate date){
        EventListFragment eventListFragment = new EventListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(DATE_ARG, date);
        eventListFragment.setArguments(args);
        return eventListFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_list, container, false);

        // Setup recyclerview
        RecyclerView eventRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        eventRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Get date
        LocalDate eventDate = (LocalDate) getArguments().getSerializable(DATE_ARG);

        // Set adapter
        mEventAdapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity(), getEvents(eventDate));
        eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEventAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

`getEvents()` is just a private function to return events for a given date. I have used the debugger as well as unit tests to verify that it works properly. The debugger shows that it pulls the proper list for each Fragment, but as I explained they are not displayed properly.

Here is the relevant code for the parent Fragment:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

        // Get and set up viewpager
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.event_view_pager);
        EventFragmentAdapter eventFragmentAdapter = new EventFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getEventDates());
        viewPager.setAdapter(eventFragmentAdapter);

        // Get and set up tablayout
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.event_tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Similar to the last one, `getEventDates()` just pulls the dates that events are taking place. For testing purposes at the moment, I am hard coding a returned list of dates as we don't have our database set up yet. I pulled this method out because I want the app to be able to function again in 2016, which may have different dates:

```
private List<LocalDate> getEventDates(){
    List<LocalDate> eventDates = new ArrayList<>();

    eventDates.add(new LocalDate(2015, 10, 17));
    eventDates.add(new LocalDate(2015, 10, 18));

    return eventDates;
}
```

The last bit of relevant code is for the FragmentStatePagerAdapter I am using for my ViewPager:

```
public class EventFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<LocalDate> mEventDates;

    public EventFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<LocalDate> eventDates){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.mEventDates = eventDates;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return EventListFragment.newInstance(mEventDates.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEventDates.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mEventDates.get(position).dayOfWeek().getAsText();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why both lists are always the same, and are based on the last tab in the ViewPager? I assume that somehow they are referencing the same RecyclerView or the same RecyclerViewAdapter, but I don't have any static fields for those so I am not sure how it is happening.

Comment: Everything looks right. Could you show us your getEventDates code?

Comment: Are you sure that `getEvents()` is not returning the same dataset of each `LocalDate`?  As small test, what happens if you move the `ViewPager` on the `Activity` ?

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques for testing purposes right now, I have just hardcoded the dates that I returned. I return a `List<LocalDate>` object that has dates 2015-10-17 and 2015-10-18. I am still working on a way to pull these events from a database later on, so the app will still apply to our event in 2016. But that's all it does is return those two dates.

Comment: @Blackbelt I have used the debugger to verify that Saturday's Fragment returns a list of count 2, and Sunday's returns a list of count 0. The ViewPager is not inside the Activity, but in a Fragment, so I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.

Comment: @McAdam331 have you tried to instantiate this fragments hardcoded?

Comment: I mean, separated in constructor of this Adapter.

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques No, I haven't. Which snippet are you suggestion I hardcode? Do you mean pass in an ArrayList of Fragments to the pageradapter, instead of passing in a list of dates?

Comment: I will show you in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84943/discussion-between-rodrigo-henriques-and-mcadam331).

Comment: I just tried removing the `EventAdapter ` as a class level variable and instead recreating a new object each time inside of the `onCreateView` and the behavior is the same as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A long hunt and an anti-climactic solution(as with most difficult bugs). Also a bit unfair since the bug isn't in the code posted above, I had to hunt down your git project to figure it out. The bug is in `EventAdapter`:

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final List<Event> mEvents;
    private final Context mContext;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> events){
        this.mContext = context;
        mEvents = events;
    }
    ...
}
```

`mEvents` is static!... so it's shared across all instances of `mEvents`. This explains the bug perfectly since updates to it last will set the values for all `EventAdapters`.

It looks like you made `mEvents` static so that you could access it within your `ViewHolders`. Instead you can just store the individual Event within the `ViewHolder` and drop the dangerous static modifier. On the flip-side, hooray for Open Source Projects!

Comment: WOW. Good catch. I don't think I made that static intentionally, AS must have done it so it was used else where. I will try this out when I'm home this evening and will let you know.

Comment: You are right that it was static so it could be viewed inside the ViewHolder. Any idea how I can store the individual event inside the viewholder?

Comment: The Event is not available initially when you create the ViewHolder within onCreateViewHolder(). Add the Event as a new private field to your ViewHolder and then set it within onBindViewHolder().

Comment: Oh, duh. I'll try that out! I can't award the bounty yet, but it's all yours.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen your code and I totally agree with Travor - you're using a static member, that is replaced every time you create a new Adapter (and so it gets just the last page data). I've modified your project a little bit, to make it work properly. Take a look at it, hope it can be useful.

EventFragment: replace getFragmentManager with getChildFragmentManager since you need EventListFragment to be handle by EventFragment fragment manager and not by the activity fragment manager

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

        // Get and set up viewpager
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.event_view_pager);
        EventFragmentAdapter eventFragmentAdapter = new EventFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getEventDates());
        viewPager.setAdapter(eventFragmentAdapter);

        // Get and set up tablayout
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.event_tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the event dates for the hackathon so that the proper events can be displayed.
     * @return
     */
    private List<LocalDate> getEventDates(){
        List<LocalDate> eventDates = new ArrayList<>();

        eventDates.add(new LocalDate(2015, 10, 17));
        eventDates.add(new LocalDate(2015, 10, 18));

        return eventDates;
    }
}
```

EventListFragment - I've modified the query, since the sqlite query doesn't work with my locale (italian)

```
public class EventListFragment extends Fragment{

    private EventAdapter mEventAdapter;

    private static final String TAG = EventListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String DATE_ARG = "eventDate";

    public static EventListFragment newInstance(LocalDate date){
        EventListFragment eventListFragment = new EventListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(DATE_ARG, date);
        eventListFragment.setArguments(args);
        return eventListFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_list, container, false);

        // Setup recyclerview
        RecyclerView eventRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        eventRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Get date
        LocalDate eventDate = (LocalDate) getArguments().getSerializable(DATE_ARG);

        // Set adapter
        mEventAdapter = new EventAdapter(getEvents(eventDate));
        eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEventAdapter);

        Log.v(TAG, eventRecyclerView.toString());

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the events for the given date for the fragment.
     */
    private List<Event> getEvents(LocalDate date){
        List<Event> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

        String dateString = Utility.getDBDateString(date);
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                GHContract.EventEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ "*", "substr(" + GHContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_TIME + ",0,11)" },
                "substr(" + GHContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_TIME + ",0,11) = ? ",
                new String[]{dateString},
                GHContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_TIME
        );

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            returnList.add(new Event(cursor));
            dateList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GHContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_TIME)));
        }

        cursor.close();

        return returnList;
    }
}
```

EventAdapter - removed the static keyword and the reference to the activity context (you need to get the context somewhere else)

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Event> mEvents;

    public EventAdapter(List<Event> events){
        mEvents = events;
    }

    /**
     * Inflates the view for Event items.
     */
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_event, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    /**
     * Binds the data for an event to its view.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Event event = mEvents.get(position);
        holder.timeView.setText(Utility.getTimeString(event.getTime()));
        holder.titleView.setText(event.getTitle());
        holder.locationView.setText(event.getLocation());

        // If reminder time is not null, show check mark. If it is, show plus.
        if(event.getReminderTime() != null){
            holder.alarmView.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on));
        } else{
            holder.alarmView.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_alarm));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEvents.size();
    }

    /**
     * Retains a reference to the view so `findViewById` calls are only made once for the adapter.
     */
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public final TextView timeView;
        public final TextView titleView;
        public final TextView locationView;
        public final ImageView alarmView;

        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
            titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
            locationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
            alarmView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_add_reminder);
            alarmView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the click a user makes on the alarm image view.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnEventReminderClickListener activity = (OnEventReminderClickListener) v.getContext();
            activity.onEventReminderClicked(mEvents.get(getPosition()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface to call back to the activity when an alarm is clicked for an event item.
     */
    public interface OnEventReminderClickListener{
        void onEventReminderClicked(Event event);
    }
}
```

And finally the app/build.gradle, since you need to get the same version for all support libraries (recycler, card and so on)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adammcneilly.grizzhacks"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
public class EventFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<LocalDate> mEventDates;
    private List<EventListFragment> mFragments;


    public EventFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<LocalDate> eventDates){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.mEventDates = eventDates;
        this.mFragments = new ArrayList<>;
        for (LocalDate date : this.mEventDates) {
            this.mFragments.add(EventListFragment.newInstance(date));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return mFragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mEventDates.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mEventDates.get(position).dayOfWeek().getAsText();
    }
}
```

Then you check into each item of mFragents if they have the expected content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, this has the same behavior as my original code.

Comment: Please, don't keep references to Fragments. It is simply wrong, wrong as keeping references to Activity, BrodcastReceivers, ContentProviders and every kind of Context or Views!